# Need to initialize an integer linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I 'm working with expressions (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression) and I need to initialize an integer constant, but I can't get it to work.

This works fine if the integer is nullable:

```
Expression cnst;
cnst = Expression.Constant(new Nullable<int>([int value here]), typeof(Nullable<int>));
```

But now I need the constant to be just int, not Nullable. But if I use new int() I can't initialize the constant. 
Any idea on this?
How can I do it?

Comment: cnst = Expression.Constant(new int(), typeof(int)); ? It returns 0 but... its new int like u have said

Comment: I long for the days when one would write:  const int m = 3;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you've missed that you can just put the value you want:

```
Expression cnt = Expression.Constant(42, typeof(int));
```

Note that that's a simpler way of writing it for nullable values too:

```
// This is a nullable integer constant expression, with the value 42
Expression cnt = Expression.Constant(42, typeof(int?));
```

Comment: @Overlord: I doubt that there's an experienced programmer alive who hasn't had something like this :)